# Three.js rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a simple multi-res panorama in Three.js.

I have the cubic projection working with this:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(512, 512, 512, 20, 20, 10,10), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
mesh.scale.x = -1;
scene.add(mesh);
```

I add tiles to a parent object and I'm trying to get the faces of the cube to match up with the background box.

```
   var face_b = new THREE.Object3D();
       face_b.position.z = -511;
       scene.add(face_b);
   var face_f = new THREE.Object3D();
       face_f.position.z = 511;
       face_f.rotation.y = -180;
       scene.add(face_f);
   var face_l = new THREE.Object3D();
       face_l.position.z = 0;
       face_l.position.x = 512;
       face_l.rotation.y = -90;
       scene.add(face_l);
   var face_r = new THREE.Object3D();
       face_r.position.x = -512;
       face_r.position.z = 0;
       face_r.rotation.y = 90;
       scene.add(face_r);
    var face_u = new THREE.Object3D();
        face_u.position.z = -511;
        //scene.add(face_u);
    var face_d = new THREE.Object3D();
        face_d.position.z = -511;
        //scene.add(face_d);
```

The back face (b) works exactly as it should.

The rest of them appear but the rotation is all wrong and doesn't match up.

Am I using rotation in the right way?

Comment: `object.rotation` is in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lookAt( camera.position ); is what did it